# Automatically reconnect a Haskell Network connection in an idiomatic way

Tags: haskell

I've worked my way through [Don Stewart's Roll your own IRC bot tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Roll_your_own_IRC_bot), and am playing around with some extensions to it. My current code is essentially the same as the "The monadic, stateful, exception-handling bot in all its glory"; it's a bit too long to paste here unless someone requests it.

Being a Comcast subscriber, it's particularly important that the bot be able to reconnect after periods of poor connectivity. My approach is to simply time the `PING` requests from the server, and if it goes without seeing a `PING` for a certain time, to try reconnecting.

So far, the best solution I've found is to wrap the `hGetLine` in the `listen` loop with `System.Timeout.timeout`. However, this seems to require defining a custom exception so that the `catch` in `main` can call `main` again, rather than `return ()`. It also seems quite fragile to specify a timeout value for each individual `hGetLine`.

Is there a better solution, perhaps something that wraps an `IO a` like `bracket` and `catch` so that the entire main can handle network timeouts without the overhead of a new exception type?

Comment: There's no runtime performance of a new exception type relative to the built-in exceptions.  Do you mean code/maintenance overhead?  I would think that user-defined exceptions are a good thing.  Otherwise, you could change `listen` to return a `Maybe ()` on timeouts and pattern match on that instead of using exceptions.  If you change `Net` to `ReaderT Bot (MaybeT IO)` you can plumb your errors through that way.  I usually prefer this over exceptions.

Comment: You shouldn't call back into `main` from an exception handler -- GHC really should document this better. (Although, I'm actually not sure if the new `mask` functionality in GHC 7 makes this less horrible?) Rather, you should fail with some sort of error result -- a `Left` or `Nothing` or the like -- and then, *outside the handler* trap that to call into `main` again.

Comment: @sclv - yet another exception-related gotcha.  I think exceptions may be the worst product of CS since GOTO.

Comment: @sclv These issues are why the exception approach seems messy to me; I feel like I can come up with something that works, but that just doesn't feel like the right way to deal with it.

Comment: @John, haha yes, exceptions are the worst way to handle exceptional conditions except for all the alternatives :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about running a separate thread that performs all the reading and writing and takes care of periodically reconnecting the handle?

Something like this

```
 input  :: Chan Char
 output :: Chan Char

 putChar c = writeChan output c

 keepAlive = forever $ do
     h <- connectToServer
     catch
         (forever $
              do c <- readChan output; timeout 4000 (hPutChar h c); return ())
         (\_ -> return ())
```

The idea is to encapsulate all the difficulty with periodically reconnecting into a separate thread.

Comment: This looks like the way to go now that I've seen how asynchronous exceptions work. Simon Marlow's parallelism & concurrency tutorial has a nice section on these: http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/par-tutorial.pdf